# Rails and mongo embed relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, bson

I'm trying to create some relations on Mongoid but when I try to save the inner object or add it to the `user.personal_accounts` collection I get the following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `bson_type' for #<Bank:0x71c01a8>
```

My Object in rails console is correct

```
#<PersonalAccount _id: 56e87f669c27691be0d3041b, number: "55", active: true, bank: #<Bank _id: 56d74cdb9c27692fb4bd4c6d, code: 123, name: "Bradesco", country: "USA">>
```

My mappings

```
class PersonalAccount
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :number, type: String
  field :active, type: Boolean
  field :bank, type: Bank

  embedded_in :user
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :first_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String
  embeds_many :personal_accounts

end

class Bank
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :code, type: Integer
  field :name, type: String
  field :country, type: String
end
```

The mapping that I was expecting is:

- User

  - PersonalAccounts

    - Bank
- Bank

As I have read that I need to copy the outer bank to each PersonalAccount.

I have already tried the following [Link](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-4229)

Versions installed:

```
bson (4.0.2)
bson_ext (1.5.1)
mongoid (5.0.2)
mongo (2.2.4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of your problem is right here:

```
field :bank, type: Bank
```

MongoDB doesn't know how to store a `Bank` so Mongoid will try to convert it to something that MongoDB will understand while Mongoid is preparing the data for the database, hence the `NoMethodError`.

Presumably you want `Bank` to exist as its own collection and then each `PersonalAccount` would refer to a `Bank`. That would be a standard `belongs_to` setup:

```
class PersonalAccount
  #... but no `field :bank`
  belongs_to :bank
end
```

That will add a `field :bank_id, :type => BSON::ObjectId` to `PersonalAccount` behind the scenes and hook up accessor (`bank`) and mutator (`bank=`) methods for you.

Normally you'd want the other half of the relation in `Bank`:

```
class Bank
  #...
  has_many :personal_accounts
end
```

but that won't work (as you found out) because `PersonalAccount` is embedded inside `User` so `Bank` can't get at it directly. Keep in mind that `embeds_one` is just a fancy of wrapping the Mongoid machinery around a `Hash` field in a document and `embeds_many` is just a fancy way of wrapping the Mongoid machinery around an array of hashes inside another document; embedded documents don't have an independent existence, they're just a part of their parent.

Comment: I've tried this solution but it returns to me a MixedRelations Error, when I switched the PersonalAcount to has_one:bank and bank belongs_to:personal_accounts, it works on the object and I'm able to save it, but when I retrieve it again, it does not show the bank anymore

Comment: Sorry, you'd want to go with just the `belongs_to :bank` without `has_many :personal_accounts` due to the embedding. I updated the answer.